# unable to download rmarkdown package, i tried both Ri386, Rx64 and Rstudio. Here is the error from R

Tags: r, package, r-markdown

There is a binary version available but the source version is later:
          binary source needs_compilation
rmarkdown    1.4    1.6             FALSE

installing the source package ‘rmarkdown’

trying URL 'https://cran.stat.auckland.ac.nz/src/contrib/rmarkdown_1.6.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 2077665 bytes (2.0 MB)
downloaded 2.0 MB

- installing *source* package 'rmarkdown' ...
  ** package 'rmarkdown' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
  ** R
  ** inst
  ** preparing package for lazy loading
  Error in library.dynam(lib, package, package.lib) : 
  DLL 'digest' not found: maybe not installed for this architecture?
  ERROR: lazy loading failed for package 'rmarkdown'
- removing '\Akldfs12/home$/HRALXL/My Documents/R/win-library/3.2/rmarkdown'

The downloaded source packages are in
        ‘C:\Users\hralxl\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpO0hySW\downloaded_packages’
Warning messages:
1: running command '"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-32~1.4RE/bin/i386/R" CMD INSTALL -l "\Akldfs12\home$\HRALXL\My Documents\R\win-library\3.2" C:\Users\hralxl\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpO0hySW/downloaded_packages/rmarkdown_1.6.tar.gz' had status 1 
2: In install.packages(NULL, .libPaths()[1L], dependencies = NA, type = type) :
  installation of package ‘rmarkdown’ had non-zero exit status

Answer (score 0):

turns out i need a newer version of R... dumb..